# How to programmatically umount filesystems mounted by autofs?

Tags: rhel5, autofs

I have some RHEL systems where I need to disable `autofs`.
What I typically do is run a script on each of these hosts that executes something like this:

```
# /etc/init.d/autofs stop
...
# /sbin/chkconfig autofs off
...
# reboot
```

But I have a situation where doing the `reboot` will cause a problem.  I guess I could log on to each of these hosts one-by-one and execute `df` and seem what filesystems where mounted by autofs and execute by hand `umount /whatever` but that would be a pain.  Does anyone know of a slick way of shutting off `autofs` and `umount`ing the filesystems it mounted?

I do have access to `puppet`.  Maybe it would be possible for me to use puppet to edit `autofs`'s config files and then `service autofs reload`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `umount -a -t autofs`.

This will umount every `autofs` mount.

Comment: That's the ticket! Thanks. Found I had to use `umount -a -t nfs`.